# How can I deserialize an ADO.NET DataTable that contains null values using Json.NET?

Tags: ado.net, json.net

I am attempting to use [Newtonsoft.Json.Net35](http://json.codeplex.com/) Version 4.0.2.0 to deserialize an ADO.NET DataTable that contains null values.  Serialization works fine:

```
    [Test]
    public void SerializeDataTableWithNull()
    {
        var table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("item");
        table.Columns.Add("price", typeof(double));
        table.Rows.Add("shirt", 49.99);
        table.Rows.Add("pants", 54.99);
        table.Rows.Add("shoes"); // no price

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table);
        Assert.AreEqual(@"["
            + @"{""item"":""shirt"",""price"":49.99},"
            + @"{""item"":""pants"",""price"":54.99},"
            + @"{""item"":""shoes"",""price"":null}]", json);
    }
```

Deserialization works fine if values are missing:

```
    [Test]
    public void DerializeDataTableWithImplicitNull()
    {
        const string json = @"["
            + @"{""item"":""shirt"",""price"":49.99},"
            + @"{""item"":""pants"",""price"":54.99},"
            + @"{""item"":""shoes""}]";
        var table = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json);
        Assert.AreEqual("shirt", table.Rows[0]["item"]);
        Assert.AreEqual("pants", table.Rows[1]["item"]);
        Assert.AreEqual("shoes", table.Rows[2]["item"]);
        Assert.AreEqual(49.99, (double)table.Rows[0]["price"], 0.01);
        Assert.AreEqual(54.99, (double)table.Rows[1]["price"], 0.01);
        Assert.IsInstanceOf(typeof(System.DBNull), table.Rows[2]["price"]);
    }
```

If, however, values are explicitly null:

```
    [Test]
    public void DerializeDataTableWithExplicitNull()
    {
        const string json = @"["
            + @"{""item"":""shirt"",""price"":49.99},"
            + @"{""item"":""pants"",""price"":54.99},"
            + @"{""item"":""shoes"",""price"":null}]";
        var table = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json);
        Assert.AreEqual("shirt", table.Rows[0]["item"]);
        Assert.AreEqual("pants", table.Rows[1]["item"]);
        Assert.AreEqual("shoes", table.Rows[2]["item"]);
        Assert.AreEqual(49.99, (double)table.Rows[0]["price"], 0.01);
        Assert.AreEqual(54.99, (double)table.Rows[1]["price"], 0.01);
        Assert.IsInstanceOf(typeof(System.DBNull), table.Rows[2]["price"]);
    }
```

DeserializeObject throws "System.ArgumentException : Cannot set Column 'price' to be null. Please use DBNull instead."  The following workaround works for my particular JSON:

```
        var regex = new Regex(@",?""[_\w]+"":null");
        var nullless = regex.Replace(json, string.Empty);
        var table = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(nullless);
```

but like all regular expression-based kludges this is clearly brittle.

Finally, the questions:

1. Is this a bug?
2. Json.NET has many events that can be hooked.  Is there a way to get notified when a when a null value is encountered and explicitly set the value to System.DBNull?

Thanks in advance,

Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug which is easily fixed by replacing

```
dr[columnName] = reader.Value
```

with

```
dr[columnName] = reader.Value ?? System.DBNull.Value
```

in [Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.DataTableConverter](http://json.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/60444#435790).  I have entered an [issue](http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/20670) in the tracker.

Comment: [fixed](http://json.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/60604).  Thanks James.