# How to handle DBnull when serializing DataSets and DataTables to JSON using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, wcf, json, serialization, json.net

I get the following error:

> "StrongTypingException - The value for column '{ColumnName}' in table '{TableName}' is DBNull."

when I try to serialize an DataTable with some null values to JSON using JSON.NET.

This is the code:

```
var dataSet= new DsGameInformatie();
var adapter = new GameTableAdapter();
adapter.FillByGameCategoryID(dataSet.Games, 1);
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings 
{ 
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, 
    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore, 
    ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace, 
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore, 
    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore
};

return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataSet.Games, Formatting.None, settings);
```

Obviously I am doing something wrong. Am I missing something? How do I handle those DBNull values so that I don't get exceptions?

Comment: You will probably have to do that in the FillByGameCategoryID method. Possibly rite your own Convert function there to handle nulls, and return string.Empty. What line is throwing your error?

Answer (score 2):

There was a bug related to nulls in DataTables that is now fixed in Json.NET 4.0 Release 3

See [How can I deserialize an ADO.NET DataTable that contains null values using Json.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902350/how-can-i-deserialize-an-ado-net-datatable-that-contains-null-values-using-json) and the associated issue [Null values should be represented as System.DBNull when deserializing a DataTable](http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/20670).

Comment: I think that is rather a bug in .NET related to DBNull that is now *avoided* in Json.NET ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your DataSet comes from the DataSet designer, you can change how it handles null values.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya91ataz(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: This is very useful, it helps for mosts values, although I am still getting an Exception for the DateTime time. I can't change the NullValue handling of a column with type DateTime. How can I go around this?

Comment: I've never tried this, but you might be able to move your DateTime property to the other side of the DataSet's partial class. I'll try to give you an example when I'm near a machine with a C# compiler

Answer (score -1):

This is what i use and by default.Net does well. See if this works for you:

```
return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Just pass the IEnumerable to the Json function.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey, I have tried your approach but my compiler doesn't recognize Json and JsonRequestBehaviour

Comment: You will need to add a
`using System.Web.Mvc`
for this to work.

Comment: I should have said I am not using MVC. But I imported the System.Web.Mvc library, it recognizes JsonRequestBehaviour now but it still doens't recognize "Json("

Comment: Then it gives me the error : "Cannot use the iternal method "Json" here" ;) But I feel we're getting there though. Thanks for all the help so far

Comment: I made my class inherit from Controller, but now it returns a JsonResult,and the browser gives me the following error:Uncaught Sys.Net.WebServiceFailedException: Sys.Net.WebServiceFailedException: The server method 'GetGames' failed with the following error: